# Android studio login always get failed

Tags: php, android, authentication

I'm trying to create a login page and am always getting failed status.

```
package netinvoicesolo.centrumfurniture.myapplication;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.Toast;

import static android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.startActivity;

public class SigninActivity  extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{
    private Context context;

    //flag 0 means get and 1 means post.(By default it is get.)
    public SigninActivity(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute(){

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

        try{
            String username = (String)arg0[0];
            String password = (String)arg0[1];

            String link="http://192.168.0.1/invoicesolo/web/index.php?r=android/login";
            String data  = URLEncoder.encode("UserLogin[username]", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8");
            data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("UserLogin[password]", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");
            data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("yt0", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("Login", "UTF-8");

            URL url = new URL(link);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());

            wr.write( data );
            wr.flush();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;

            // Read Server Response
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line);
                break;
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        System.out.println("Resulted Value: " + result);
        if (result.equals("success")){
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(context, MenuActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(context, result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

and on PHP side, i put `echo 'success';` inside action "android/login" controller.

When i run, it always throw and exception.

```
Exception: http://192.168.0.1/invoicesolo/web/index.php?r=android/login
```

Can somebody help?

Thanks.

Comment: What exception does it throw and on what line does it throw it?

Comment: You need to put logcat error here